# Dockerfile for Python DJango failing on COPY

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that fails on build with the error;

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder476469130/requirements.txt: no such file or directory

The error occurs on the COPY line for the requirments.txt file. I use a pretty standard Dockerfile;

```
FROM python:3.6.7-slim

# Version: 1.4
# Dockerfile to build the coroner container.

# Install Python and Package Libraries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libffi-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    net-tools \
    nano

ARG PROJECT=coroner
ARG PROJECT_DIR=/var/www/${PROJECT}
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR

COPY requirements.txt $PROJECT_DIR/requirments.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r $PROJECT_DIR/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8888
STOPSIGNAL SIGINT
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py"]
CMD ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8888"]
```

I am bashing my head against this and have been praying at the church of google for a while now. I have checked the context and it seems to be correct. my build command is;

`sudo docker build -t coroner:dev .`

Docker Version `Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c`

Can somebody put me out of my misery, please?

Comment: The _destination_ of that `COPY` command has a typo (`requirments.txt`, missing an "e" in the middle) but that won't cause the error you show, unless the file name in your local source tree is similarly misspelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo in 'requirements.txt' in the destination, you've put 'requirments.txt'.

However, because you're simply copying this to where you've specified your WORKDIR, you can just do:

```
COPY requirements.txt .
```

The file will then be copied into your CWD.

Comment: Thanks man, I need to stop coding so late, errr early as the case might be...